# Golang: Hello world doesn't print to screen and program doesnt exit

Tags: go

When I run the following code with the command "go.exe run main.go", the program doesnt print text to the screen or exit.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){
    fmt.Println("Hello world")
}
```

go.exe version = go version go.1.5.1 windows/amd64

set GOARCH=386

set GOBIN=

set GOEXE=.exe

set GOHOSTARCH=386

set GOHOSTOS=windows

set GOOS=windows

set GOPATH=C:\project

set GORACE=

set GOROOT=C:\Go

set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_386

set GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=

set CC=gcc

set GOGCCFLAGS=-m32 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0

set CXX=g++

set CGO_ENABLED=1

Any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks

EDIT:

I tried uninstalling the windows/amd64 version and installing windows/386 to no avail. It's installed in c:\Go and the PATH is set. I'm using windows 10.

Line feeds

```
package mainLF
LF
import "fmt"LF
LF
func main(){LF
    fmt.Println("Hello world")LF
}LF
```

The following doesn't print to the command prompt either.

```
package main

//import "fmt"

func main(){
    println("Hello world")
}
```

The following gives the error "fmt imported but not used" so it must be doing something.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){

}
```

GOROOT is set to C:\Go\

PATH: C:\Go\bin

[Image showing how I'm running the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfu9k.jpg)

EDIT: New Image

[Updated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58Asf.jpg)

Comment: Works flawlessly for me. Please show your directory structure and the commands you used for building it.

Comment: The filepath is c:\project\main.go and I try and run it with the command go.exe run c:\project\main.go. It just hangs.

Comment: The EOL characters are just line-feeds.

Comment: Not sure what could be happening but since you are using c:\project as your project directory I would recommend you to read this https://golang.org/doc/code.html

Comment: In your question, you say you're running "go.exe run main.go", in the comments "go.exe run c:\project\main.go", and in the attached image "go run main.go".  Not sure where to start with this.

Comment: Hi I tried both "go.exe run c:\project\main.go" and "go run main.go" from the project folder. Before I ran these commands I ran "cd c:\project" in the command prompt. Go.exe has been set as a PATH variable so I can use either go or go.exe.

Comment: few primary checks that could also cause such error are 1. saving the main file. 2. run "go install" on the terminal you are from which you are running the code.
let me know if any of this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem on a Windows 10 system. Running `go run main.go` would not print anything, while `go build main.go` followed by `.\main.exe` would work correctly and print out "hello, world".

The problem was due to the Comodo antivirus software quarantining the go.exe process as part of its [Auto Containment](https://containment.comodo.com/how-it-works/) feature. I believe the `go run` command compiles and tries to load the executable binary code of main.go into the same process, which triggers the Auto Containment to isolate the output of the application.

The initial fix was to disable Auto Containment via the Comodo Antivirus settings. Upon disabling this feature, `go run main.go` began to work properly.

The permanent fix was to [add an "ignore" rule](https://help.comodo.com/topic-399-1-790-10386-.html) for the go.exe executable. This allows the Auto Containment feature to be enabled but `go run` to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder named ~/sample (Where ~ means your home directory)
From the terminal you can do this by entering the following commands:

```
mkdir sample
```

Below program for hello world display

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
fmt.Println("Hello World")
}
```

save it as main.go in the folder we just created.
Open up a new terminal and type in the following:

```
cd sample
go run main.go
```

Comment: I'm using windows 10. I followed your instructions and it doesnt print anything to the command prompt. I have gopath set to "set GOPATH=C:\project" so the file was stored in "c:\project\sample\main.go"

Comment: mkdir, cd and ~ are not things in Windows world, as far as I know.

Comment: @Arjun PowerShell only, it seems http://superuser.com/questions/332871/what-is-the-equivalent-of-linuxs-tilde-in-windows

Comment: @PatrickCollins Oops! I did not know that. Thanks! :) But cd, mkdir are supported.